# How can I overwrite local settings in apt install

Tags: apt, bash, package-management, dpkg

I'm trying to avoid the package configuration window in a bash script.

I want my script to install the package, and overwrite the configuration files,  without issuing any prompt requiring a response.

I tried to:

```
apt install -yq libpam-pwquality

apt -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install libpam-pwquality

apt -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confnew" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" install libpam-pwquality

apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confnew install libpam-pwquality
```

But, as shown in the screenshot, a prompt is appearing, so my script is not working properly. =(

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the decision by myself:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt -y install libpam-pwquality
```

This command will install the package without any questions or windows, so bash-script will not be stopped by dpkg, but it will not overwrite local-changed files.

Works for me anyway, because you can overwrite this files later by using this command:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive pam-auth-update --force
```

Found the decision here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/682662